How do you encode with UTF-8 and or properly select specific columns when reading a csv?
I am trying to read in a very large file by selecting specific columns to make it more manageable. R says that this must be encoded as "UTF-8" even though I have already specified this in my code. What am I doing wrong here?
kings_precincts_2023 <- fread("kings_precincts_2023.csv",
                          encoding = "UTF-8",
                          header = TRUE,
                          select = c("CountyName", 
                                     "PrecinctName", 
                                     "JudicialName", 
                                     "PrecinctName", 
                                     "CountyLegName",
                                     "CityCouncilName",
                                     "CD",
                                     "HD",
                                     "SD",
                                     "City"))


Are you getting an error message? What is the exact message you are getting? You are setting encoding="UTF-8" when reading but are you sure the file actually is UTF-8 encoded on disk? Can you provide any sort of reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions?

I'm reading through to learn more about reproducible examples but in the meantime I figured I should tell you the error message I get says: "Error in fread("kings_precincts_2023.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", header = TRUE,  :
File is encoded in UTF-16, this encoding is not supported by fread(). Please recode the file to UTF-8."

So it's telling you the file is encoded with UTF-16. That's not something you can change with a parameter to fread. You need to re-encode the file itself if you want to use fread. Depending on your operating system there may be many ways to do this. Google "convert utf-16 to utf-8" for some suggestions.

Could I alternatively just do this as read.txt or something like that? Is the issue that R can't read that encoding at all or just that the file is really utf-8 and I'm just using the wrong function?

It's possible read.txt could work. Without a file to test with I can't say for sure. The error message indicates that fread from data.table can't read the file, it doesn't necessarily mean mean that R cannot. It seems unlikely that the function would like about the true encoding but it's possible. Again, without access to the actual file I have no idea what encoding it's really using.
